# Api-platform accessing embedded relations in hydra:member

Tags: reactjs, api-platform.com

I'm using Api-Platform and React as client.

I have a Forum entity which contains other objects : an author (User entity) and a category (Category entity).

I embedded these entities with `@Groups` annotations to retrieve them more easily.

For instance, when I fetch `/api/forums/` on Postman I get this result :

```
{
"@context": "/api/contexts/Forum",
"@id": "/api/forums",
"@type": "hydra:Collection",
"hydra:member": [
    {
        "@id": "/api/forums/79",
        "@type": "Forum",
        "id": 79,
        "subject": "Sujet numéro 0",
        "message": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
        "category": {
            "@id": "/api/categories/183",
            "@type": "Category",
            "title": "Category 2"
        },
```

It seems good : we can see my category object is linked to Forum in hydra:member array, and a "title" field.

But I noticed that the result I really get is different in my react app for all my nested objects.
I only get the IRIs..

For instance with the same request :

```
...
fetch('forums')
  .then(response =>
    response
      .json()
      .then(retrieved => ({ retrieved, hubURL: extractHubURL(response) }))
  )
  .then(({ retrieved, hubURL }) => {
    retrieved = normalize(retrieved);
...
```

I get this result :

```
{
"@context": "/api/contexts/Forum",
"@id": "/api/forums",
"@type": "hydra:Collection",
"hydra:member": [
    {
        "@id": "/api/forums/79",
        "@type": "Forum",
        "id": 79,
        "subject": "Sujet numéro 0",
        "message": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
        "category": "/api/categories/183",
```

Every other fields have disapeared on "category", and I don't get why.

Could anyone help me with that ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution (how silly of me), so I share you the tip :

In src/utils/dataAccess file, there is a normalize function :

```
export function normalize(data) {
  if (has(data, 'hydra:member')) {
    // Normalize items in collections
    data['hydra:member'] = data['hydra:member'].map(item => normalize(item));
    return data;
  }

  // Flatten nested documents
  return mapValues(data, value =>
    Array.isArray(value)
      ? value.map(v => get(v, '@id', v))
      : get(value, '@id', value)
  );
}
```

It appears that this function is called after each fetch :

```
return fetch(id)
      .then(response =>
        response
          .json()
          .then(retrieved => ({ retrieved, hubURL: extractHubURL(response) }))
      )
      .then(({ retrieved, hubURL }) => {
        //retrieved = normalize(retrieved);

        dispatch(loading(false));
        dispatch(success(retrieved));
        ....
```

As you can see, I just commented the normalize line (useless in my case). Do that wherever it is needed, and everything should work again !